# Prevent page postback when user hits enter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a web form which when the user hits enter, the page will be posted back. Here's the thing: when the user clicks on the form, a control will be focused (my mouse pointer changes into the one for when you are about to click an input control) and when the enter is hit, my page will reload.

Is there a way to capture the press of any key not mattering where the user clicks on?

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Jquery example:
    //Bind this keypress function to all of the input tags 
$("input").keypress(function (evt) { 
    //Deterime where our character code is coming from within the event 
    var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode; 
    if (charCode == 13) {
     //Enter key's keycode 
    return false; 
}
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disable this in the body tag by capturing **KeyCode 13**, not sure how compatible this is across browsers.

```
<body onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery and register keyup events and just focus on the return key. Then you would just need to make sure you are reacting properly for the given this value.

$(document).on('keydown', function(e){ //logic }

Comment: Jquery solves many of the cross-browser issues also. It generally works with any browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the button being "clicked" when enter is pressed and prevent the postback/submit from happening when the user is in a input control, you need to either set your button to not postback or what I have done in the past is set a button that does nothing to set as default button for my panel in the circumstance I had.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="bDefault">
   <%-- here are all the input controls and a button that 
    now must be physically clicked to submit--%>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Button ID="bDefault" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="hidden" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

return false OnClientClick causes the button to not postback.